# How do I connect PostgreSQL with PyDev in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, pydev, tryton

I'm developing a module for Tryton, and when I'm trying to run unittest test in Eclipse with PostgreSQL and PyDev, Eclipse is not enable to connect to PostgreSQL. The test fails and raises this message:

> OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

The unittest test file is correct because if I run it in a Python console, it works correctly.

How can I integrate unittest test in Eclipse with PostgreSQL and PyDev?